# How to click the elements insde <md-dailoge-container> angularjs 2 element in selenium

Tags: angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Excel To HTML using codebeautify.org</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
    <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Excel To HTML using codebeautify.org</title>
     </head>
     <body>
      <md-dialog-container class="mat-dialog-container" role="dialog">
       <cdk-focus-trap>
        <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}-->
        <div tabindex="0"></div>
        <div class="cdk-focus-trap-content">
         <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-portal": null
}-->
         <app-confirmation-dialog _nghost-lok-51="">
          <div _ngcontent-lok-51="" class="box-holder">
           <div _ngcontent-lok-51="" class="header-row text-center-align" fxlayoutalign="space-between center" ng-reflect-klass="header-row" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" ng-reflect-align="space-between center" style="justify-content: space-between; align-items: center; align-content: center; display: flex; flex-direction: row; box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-align: center; -webkit-box-orient: horizontal; -webkit-box-direction: normal;">
            <div _ngcontent-lok-51="" class="header-title "></div>
            <div _ngcontent-lok-51="" class="close-btn">
             <i _ngcontent-lok-51="" class="icon-close"></i>
            </div>
           </div>
           <div _ngcontent-lok-51="" class="box-content">
            <div _ngcontent-lok-51="" class="content-holder text-center-align" fxlayoutalign="start start" ng-reflect-klass="content-holder" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" ng-reflect-align="start start" ng-reflect-inner-h-t-m-l="Ticket no. 
          
             <a target=&quot;_blank&quot; href=&quot;/v2/tickets/5986813&quot;> 5986813</a> &amp;#160; has been created and is unassigned" style="justify-content: flex-start; align-items: flex-start; align-content: flex-start; display: flex; flex-direction: row; box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-pack: start; -webkit-box-align: start; -webkit-box-orient: horizontal; -webkit-box-direction: normal;">Ticket no. 
          
             <a target="_blank" href="/v2/tickets/5986813"> xyz</a> &nbsp; has been created
         
            </div>
            <div _ngcontent-lok-51="" class="action-container" fxlayoutalign="end end" ng-reflect-align="end end" style="justify-content: flex-end; align-items: flex-end; align-content: flex-end; display: flex; flex-direction: row; box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-pack: end; -webkit-box-align: end; -webkit-box-orient: horizontal; -webkit-box-direction: normal;">
             <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
             <button _ngcontent-lok-51="" class="od-button small action-button" style="margin-right: 0;" type="button"> Ok </button>
            </div>
           </div>
          </div>
         </app-confirmation-dialog>
        </div>
        <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}-->
        <div tabindex="0"></div>
       </cdk-focus-trap>
      </md-dialog-container>
     </body>
    </html>
   </body>
  </html>
```

In the above code snippet i want to perform the following actions
1. I want to read the ticket ID
2. click on yes button

I tried with multiple solutions but getting error message as 
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: 
i have used xpath as 
1. //a[contains(@href,"/v2/tickets/")]
2. //div[normalize-space(text())='Ticket no.']/a

Please some one help me to find the solution for it

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code with Explicit wait which waits for element to be present :

```
    By ticketID = By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'/v2/tickets/')] ");
    By okButton = By.cssSelector("button.od-button.small.action-button");

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(ticketID));

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'/v2/tickets/')] ")).getText();

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(okButton));

    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.od-button.small.action-button")).click();
```

Comment: Thanks @kushal. It has worked. But i didn't use presenceOfElementLocated instead i have used waituntilelementvisible/ isvisble.

Comment: Hmm.. the point here is while working g with Angular JS elements you have to usually wait until the angular JS object have loaded, which could be in the form of any of the several Expected Conditions.